# Change Multiindex values in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, multi-index

This is may DataFrame  (two columns : `name` and `age` and two indices : `player_id` and `season_id`).

|  |  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| player_id | season_id |  |  |
| 991 | 28 | Fabio | 33 |
| 1028 | 28 | Luigi | 25 |

I want to change a value inside the MultiIndex in this way:

|  |  | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| player id | season id |  |  |
| 991 | 26 | Fabio | 33 |
| 1028 | 28 | Luigi | 25 |

I've tried different ways without any effect.

- df.loc[[(991,28)]].index.set_levels = (991,26)
- df.loc[[(991,28)]].index.set_levels([991,26], inplace=True)
- df.loc[[(991,28)]].index = df.loc[[(991,28)]].index.set_levels([991,26])

Has someone some suggests?

Comment: You probably have to build a new index, since index are mostly immutable

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with `if-else` and recreate `df.index`:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(991,26) if x == (991,28) else x for x in df.index], 
                                     names=df.index.names)
print (df)
                      name  age
player_id season_id            
991       26         Fabio   33
1028      28         Luigi   25
```

Answer (score 0):

this code should work either:

```
df.index.set_levels([26,28], level='season_id', inplace=True)
```